# Angular form.fieldName.$invalid not working inside ng-class attribute

Tags: angularjs

I have already solved this problem, but it took me a while to realize what I did wrong. It's a very simple mistake, but I figured I'd post it here in hopes I can save someone else some work in case they run across the same mistake.

I was trying to use simple Angular validation to set a class on an input field based on whether it was valid. I failed to realize it wasn't working because I specified the name of my form with ng-form. So using `$scope.form` or the actual value of `name` attribute of the form did not work. Of course, the examples below are simplified and a much larger form could make this mistake much harder to recognize.

Comment: If you just wanted to show it being valid or invalid, you can just use CSS as well, as AngularJS automatically applies some classes. i.e. **valid:** `input.ng-valid { border: 2px solid limegreen; }` or **invalid:**  `input.ng-invalid { border: 2px solid red; }`

Comment: @Austin, just adding the CSS would not produce the desired result in my case. Doing so would highlight all required fields as invalid before any data was even entered into them. Using `input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty { border: 2px solid red; }` would also not work in highlighting blank required fields on blur. In my case I am actually performing validation at multiple levels in the form and flipping another validation variable, so something like `ng-class="error: showError && form1.myField.$invalid"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a failed example:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-form="form1">
<input type="text" name="myField" ng-class="error: myForm.myField.$invalid"/>
</form>
```

Here is a successful example:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-form="form1">
<input type="text" name="myField" ng-class="error: form1.myField.$invalid"/>
</form>
```

Comment: <form name="myForm" ng-form="form1"> is this work? That is having multiple directives on same DOM element. Should result with an error